# Looking for reason of two projects with different folder on laravel pointing to same website on localhost

Tags: php, css, url

I've two projects on laravel with different folder as in:

```
localhost/hgwebstore/public/    -- Working for more than 2 months
localhost/exposition/public/    -- Recently created
```

Both of the projects are created from composer.
My problem is while I open the first URL initially, Its content loads normally. But as I try to open second URL, instead of showing the content of second URL its pointing to first URL.

URL: localhost/hgwebstore/public/
[image]

Now If I try to open URL: localhost/exposition/public/
[image]

Here the style changes because the CSS files are not found in later URL.

But problem goes weirdest when I restart apache server and visit the later URL at first. Here, the content of later URL is displayed in both of the URL.

Visiting URL :localhost/exposition/public/
[image]

Visiting URL: localhost/hgwebstore/public/
[image]

How is this issue occurred? How could the issue be resolved?

Comment: While debuggin the bootstrap/autoload.php, I found ____DIR____ returning the path of previously opened URL. Is the issue somewhere related to opcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the reason the webserver behaving such is due to enable of APC extension that has taken the same cache for both websites. By disabling, the APC fixed the issue.